# Is it safe to use the AC if the pressure is too high?

Tags: honda, ac, accord, pressure

My dealer replaced the AC compressor in my 1997 Accord recently.  However, they said the pressure in the system is too high due to contamination and I need to replace several other parts of the AC system (condenser, receiver drier, expansion valve, and various pipes/hoses).  I had another mechanic look at it, and he agreed that I need to replace several more parts.

I can still feel cold air coming out of the vents, although on hot days it is weak.

I have also noticed a new problem since the compressor was replaced.  On a couple of occasions, either when stopped at a red light or while driving very slowly, the car has started jerking or shaking and the tachometer bounced up and down.  The jerking/shaking stops when I turn off the AC, and it may start again when I turn the AC back on.  The dealer and mechanic both said it's because the AC pressure is too high.

Is it okay to continue using the AC if the pressure is too high?  I have not noticed any jerking/shaking while driving at higher speeds.  I could always turn the AC off when idling and turn it back on when driving again.

Answer (score 1):

It kind of depends on exactly *why* the pressure is too high - there can be multiple causes but in general it's a bad idea to continue to run the A/C if the system is over-pressurized.

You can do all sorts of nasty damage to parts of the system by doing so (and for nasty, read *expensive*).

It sucks but I think you're best off playing it safe and not using it until you can get the further work done.

Comment: While it may not be so on a 97 Accord, I believe most newer vehicles have over pressure switches installed ... if there is too much pressure, it shuts the system down. This may be of note to anyone who has a newer vehicle with this installed in it.